# laravelのif()内について

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

laravelの条件節の分け方の勉強をしており、例で`@if($error->has('xxx'))`とよく見るのですが、このxxxは何を示しているのですか？
当たり前のようにでてくるのできっと常識なのだと思いますが、答えが見つけられせん。

お心当たりある方はご教授いただけますと幸いです。

追記
分かりにくいようでしたので具体例上げます。
以下を参照していました。

[Laravelのバリデーションにはフォームリクエストを使おう - Qiita](https://qiita.com/sakuraya/items/abca057a424fa9b5a187)

```
/** 特定のエラーの表示 */
@if($errors->has('username'))
    <div class="error">
        <p>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

1. 例えばここの'username'は何を示しているんでしょうか？
2. $errorsの中の入力内容userみたいな感じかと思ったのですが、そもそも$errorsの中身は？
3. firstというのもどこからきたのでしょう？secondやthirdも存在するのでしょうか？

Comment: 「例」がなにを指しているのか、どのようなコードが例で挙げられているのかもう少し詳しく説明されないと何を指しているのかあいまいで回答が得にくいかもしれません…

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます、見やすいです、参考にします。

Comment: 過去質問のいくつかに回答が付いていますので、もし解決した場合には最も役立った回答を **承認** してください。質問者が承認を行う事で、他のユーザーからも解決済みであることが分かるようになります。 / 回答が付いても未解決であるなら、追加の情報を書き込みなどしてぜひフォローアップをお願いします。 - 参考: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まずは公式のドキュメントやその[日本語訳](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/ja/validation.html#working-with-error-messages)などを参照されることをお勧めします。

さて、ここでいう`$error`は単にエラーいうよりバリデーションの結果ですね。

たとえば参照されている記事にある

```
    [
        'username' => 'required|max:20',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:100',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ];
```

というバリデーションルールを考えてみます。

1. ここで質問中のxxxに入りうるのは`username`, `email`, `password`のいずれかです。基本的にはバリデーションルールのキーと思ってください。
2. `$errors`の実態は`Illuminate\Support\MessageBag`です。これは各キーに対応するメッセージを内部的に**配列で**持っています。

   1. `has` はこの中身が**1つ以上存在する**場合にtrueを返します
   2. `first` は配列の先頭の値を返します
      バリデーションなのでメッセージは複数存在する場合があるわけです。複数表示しても邪魔なので先頭だけ表示することはよくあります。（この順番がバリデーションルール指定順だったかは忘れましたが）
      `first`の代わりに`get`を使用するとこれを配列ですべて取得できます。 [全フィールドの全エラーメッセージ取得](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/ja/validation.html#working-with-error-messages)

      をご覧ください。
3. 蛇足ですが「要素が一つ以上存在する」配列のようなオブジェクトにおいて先頭の値は使用機会が比較的多くなります。1つだけの結果を返すクエリなんかもそうです。そのためLaravelではコレクションのようなクラスではその先頭を得るための[`first`](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/ja/collections.html#method-first)が用意されていることがしばしばあります。

(確認せずに書いているので一部誤りがある気がします)

Comment: 詳細の解説ありがとうございます。各記号や変数、単語が何を示しているのか全く理解できなかったので助かります。質問で書いた箇所は何を示しているのか理解できましたので、教えていただいたHPも参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: あてはまるものが1つ以上とありましたが、countなどは入れずに勝手にerrorがあると判断すれば数えてくれる形式なのでしょうか？

Comment: countなどは入れずに~が何を指しているのかよくわからないのですがおそらくその認識でいいかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。単純に一つ、二つ、と個数が発生する以上count($error)と設定するのが通例なのかと思っていたので、countという文字を入れずに数えることができるのか疑問に思ったのでお聞きしました。

Comment: はい。 `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` ミドルウェアが使用されてい手上書きされていない限り[View上の`$errors`自体はMessageBagであることが保証されている](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/ja/validation.html#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)わけですし、[`has`はその中身を確認している](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/v5.7.23/MessageBag.php#L106)ので。